# React native {something } is not a fucntion

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I get an error like this when fetching json data in react-native

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class Liste extends Component {
  state = {data: []};
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({data: response.data});
    });
  }

  renderData() {
    return this.state.data.map(responseData => (
      <Text>{responseData.first_name}</Text>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Gelen Data' + this.state);
    console.log('render');
    return <View>{this.renderData()}</View>;
  }
}

export default Liste;
```

[this.state.data.map is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16pQX.png)

why am i getting this error.
can you help me

Comment: Check out `response.data`. You're probably setting data to something that is not an array.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved this way render.data.data so it’s correct mapping like this

Answer (score 0):

In class components you need to bind the function inside the component

```
class Liste extends Compoennt {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.renderData = this.renderData.bind(this)
    }

    render() {
        //your normal code
    }

}
```

Or you can simply use an arrow function

```
class Liste extends Compoennt {

    renderData = () => {}

    render() {
        //your normal code
    }

}
```

Regardless of this, you might want to consider switching to functional components and using hooks, totally worth it